# Anagram Program Testing

Tags: c++, anagram

My anagram program works great in my dev-cpp but in any online tester throw wrong answer on any testing anagram. Can someone help me?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    char input1[10000];
    char input2[10000];
    cin >> input1;
    getchar();
    cin >> input2;
    getchar();

    int leng;
    leng = strlen(input1);
    bool output[leng];

    for(int i=0; i<leng; i++){
            for(int y=0; y<leng; y++){
                    if( input1[i] == input2[y] ){
                        output[i] = true;
                    }
            }
    }

    for(int o=0; o<leng; o++ ){
        if( (o+1) == leng){
            if( output[o] == true){
                 cout << "ano" << endl;
                 break;
            }
        }else if(output[o] == true) {
                 continue;
        }
        cout << "nie" << endl;
        break;
    }


    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example in your question which works for you, but not online?

Comment: Probably...

kalerab
mrkvicka

...in pc it throws me "no", but online "yes", but im not sure about that example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have issue with your algorithm. Imagine the following scenario:

```
Input1: ab
Input2: cdefab
```

Your algorithm will return OK because it will only check that a & b characters of input1 are present in input2.

Same problem with example such as:

```
Input1: aaaaaa
Input2: a
```

Or:

```
Input1: aaaab
Input2: bbbba
```

You can change your algorithm by:

- Counting characters using an array of 256 (index of your character in ASCII) `int` initialized to 0. Increment for input1 and decrement for input2, in the end your array should be filled with 0. O(n) algo
- Sorting your two inputs and comparing them character after character. O(n^2) algo

You can find more details about those algo [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-whether-two-strings-are-anagram-of-each-other/).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to reinvent the wheel, there is a neat function `is_permutation` in `<algorithm>` that can make this problem trivial . .

```
#include <algorithm>

bool isAnagram(std::string a, std::string b) {
    if(a.size() == b.size()) {
        return std::is_permutation ( a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), [](char x, char y){return std::tolower(x) == std::tolower(y);} );
    }
    return false;
}
```

Just remove the binary predictate if you want case sensitivity. [Try it here](https://ideone.com/5rzNe5)

Comment: You are completely right, but I think that the OP is trying to implement his own algorithm in order to learn programming...this is just a thought of mine.

Comment: Yes, i just learn but thank guys. I know where a made a mistakes.