# Checking if two strings are anagram

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, anagram

Problem is given two strings, check whether two given strings are **anagram** of each other or not. An anagram of a string is another string that contains same characters, only the order of characters can be different. For example, “act” and “tac” are anagram of each other.

Input: 
The first line of input contains an integer T denoting the number of test cases. Each test case consist of two strings in 'lowercase' only, in a single line.

Output:
Print "YES" without quotes if the two strings are anagram else print "NO".

Constraints:
1 ≤ T ≤ 30
1 ≤ |s| ≤ 10^16

Example:
Input:
1
allergy allergic

Output:
NO

My approach is to first check the length of strings, if they are not equal then simply print out **NO** and if they are equal then sort the strings and then compare element wise.

I am getting correct output on some simple inputs but not on complex ones as my code is not able to pass all the test cases.I am not able to figure out my mistake.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
int main() {
    int n, t=0;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        string a,b;
        cin>>a>>b;
        cout<<"\n";
        if(a.length()!=b.length())
        {
            cout<<"NO";
        }
        else
        {
            sort(a.begin(),a.end());
            sort(b.begin(),b.end());
            for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++)
            {
                if(a[i]!=b[i])
                {
                    cout<<"NO";
                    break;
                }
                t++;
            }
           if(t==a.length())
           {
               cout<<"YES";
           }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not simply do `a == b` after the sorting?

Comment: As for your current code, it's probably time to [learn how to debug your code](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Try stepping through the code line by line in a debugger for a test-case you know your program will be wrong about.

Comment: see also [`std::is_permutation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_permutation)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yeah true, thanks for improving but still not correct.It's giving me a message-> Wrong Answer. !!!Wrong Answer Possibly your code doesn't work correctly for multiple test-cases (TCs).

Comment: The expected output format is "result + newline" for each test case, not "newline + result". Some checkers are very picky about format.

Comment: @molbdnilo probably limit is calculated this way to pass (or maybe not) pass solution with sort algorithm.

Comment: @molbdnilo Yeah right, sorry actually I copy pasted it and so it came like 1016 but it's actually 10^16.

Comment: @Caleth do you know complexity of this function ? Because it seems complicated ?

And here I found [nice article](https://deque.blog/2017/04/04/lost-in-permutation-complexity/) ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anagram Program Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33120501/anagram-program-testing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code seems to give only 1 response when 2 expected.
Problem is that you don't reset your `t` variable ;) So it is always incrementing.
Example of run: https://ideone.com/IYK6Ad

Input test:

```
2
aab baa
a a
```

Output:

```
YES
```

---

**Fixed code:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
int main() {
    int n, t=0;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        string a,b;
        cin>>a>>b;
        if(a.length()!=b.length())
        {
            cout<<"NO\n";
        }
        else
        {
            sort(a.begin(),a.end());
            sort(b.begin(),b.end());
            if(a != b)
            {
                cout<<"NO\n";
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"YES\n";
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Example run](https://ideone.com/MYgIIJ)

---

Some hints about improvement of this algorithm.
For now we consider only 1 test case for checking anagram.

So in your case you have `2 * O(n * log n) complexity` mainly because of [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)(Check complexity)

Check for different size is some kind of corner case aka. quick win. So you can keep it but probably testing program will not use those ;)

Does it pass of course will be impacted on how big test cases would be and how many test cases.

Idea of improvement:

1. Count each character (we can use `std::map<char,int>` for that but accessing elements in map takes some time also. So in our case we know something about input data so we can benefit from it. It should be ASCII data so we can fit in fixed array.)
2. If count of specific char is different we know the answer!

For such solution we would get `O(n+m) + O(min(n,m))` where `n` is length of string `a` and `m` is length of `b`. Pretty better complexity.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    std::vector<int> aCountOfChars(256, 0);
    std::vector<int> bCountOfChars(256, 0);

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        string a,b;
        cin>>a>>b;
        std::vector<int> aCountOfChars(256, 0);
        std::vector<int> bCountOfChars(256, 0);

        for(int i=0;i<a.size();++i)
        {
            ++aCountOfChars[a[i]];  
        }
        for(int i=0;i<b.size();++i)
        {
            ++bCountOfChars[b[i]];  
        }

        if(aCountOfChars == bCountOfChars)
        {
            cout<<"YES\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"NO\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Run me](https://ideone.com/NxUFuQ)

---

Some test cases to check:

```
7
a b
aab baa
a a
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa b
aabba bbaaa
act tac
allergy allergic
```

[Nice article about such problem](https://deque.blog/2017/04/04/lost-in-permutation-complexity/)

Comment: Yeah you are very true. I rectified it but still not getting it correct. It's giving me a message-> Wrong Answer. !!!Wrong Answer
Possibly your code doesn't work correctly for multiple test-cases (TCs).

Comment: @DavidMi maybe you have problem with new lines ;) I think so in your case. I will update code.

Comment: @DavidMi could you give link to task if it is available online on Timus or other ACM like site ?

Comment: You are right, there was issue of newline. Now it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
static boolean isAnagram(String A, String B) {
       A=A.toLowerCase();
       B=B.toLowerCase();
       boolean f = false;
      char[] c = A.toCharArray();
      Arrays.sort(c);
      char[] d = B.toCharArray();
      Arrays.sort(d);
      String a = new String (c);
      String b = new String (d);
      if (a.equals(b)) {
          f=true;
      }
      return f;

   }
```

A sample function to check anagram in Java Programming Language.